# Formula for cycloid?

Tags: circles, pi

Is there a formula for cycloid?

My approximation is $((2\times(x\div(\pi\div2)))-(x\div(\pi\div2))^2)^.626$.

Comment: How accurate is this?

Comment: It's a bit off.

Comment: A number would be nice - relative or absolute error.

Answer (score 0):

$$x = r \cos^{-1} \left(1 - \frac{y}{r}\right) - \sqrt{y(2r - y)}$$

Comment: Not for that axis. Is there an inverse function for this?

Comment: @AnastasiaDunbar it is not possible to isolate $y$.  But with an approximation algorithm, you can find any $y$

Comment: Why is it impossible? It should be possible if it isn't prolate.

Comment: It has no loop, but still, you will not be able to isolate $y$, try it.